# Find and Click on element using Selenium, Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to click on an element and after that want to select date between today and last day.

Here is image [image]

I'm able to click on **Position Added Date** element but I'm stuck down here "How can I select First date picker and select last day, and then click on **To** and select today date.

here is `xpath`

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Position Added Date:')]/input[@class='datetime-picker-date']
```

Here is element code that is being displayed after clicking the dropdown

```
<div class="jquery-ui-v1-10-3 dropdown-filter-edit-popup group" data-bind="control: EditorPopup" style="display: block;">

    <a class="clear-filters" href="#" data-bind="click: Clear, css: { disabled: !CanClear() }">Clear Items</a>

    <button data-bind="visible: HelpButtonVisible, click: HelpClick, css: {close: HelpOpen() == true }" class="help close" style="display: none;"></button>

    <div class="filter-content" data-bind="control: EditViewModel, event: { keydown: EditorKey }"><div class="date-range-filter Edit">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">From:</label>
            <div data-bind="control: From" class=""><!-- ko if: !HideDate -->
                <input type="text" class="datetime-picker-date hasDatepicker input-sm" data-bind="value: Date, valueUpdate: 'keyup', jqWidget: { datepicker: DatePickerArgs }, assignTo: DateField, attr: { 'readonly': IsReadOnly() }, enable: IsEnabled, css: { 'input-sm': SmallSize }" id="dp1474822442990">
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: !HideTime --><!-- /ko --></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="">To:</label>
                <div data-bind="control: To" class=""><!-- ko if: !HideDate             -->
                    <input type="text" class="datetime-picker-date hasDatepicker input-sm" data-bind="value: Date, valueUpdate: 'keyup', jqWidget: { datepicker: DatePickerArgs }, assignTo: DateField, attr: { 'readonly': IsReadOnly() }, enable: IsEnabled, css: { 'input-sm': SmallSize }" id="dp1474822442991">
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko if: !HideTime --><!-- /ko --></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot go with ids, as these are dynamics.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Do those id for the input change or are they always the same? If they are static, I would recommend to hook onto those as the calendar picker "from" and "To" to make calendar show. As for the dates in the calendar, take a closer look. Perhaps there are special class names like "today" associated with todays date.

Comment: ids do change on every refresh, and `datetime-picker-date` is the class assigned with both, `To` and `From` `input` box.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening calendar and select date, you can use `.sendKeys()` to enter date in appropriate format as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
```

- Enter `From` date :-

  ```
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[data-bind*='From'] > input.datetime-picker-date"))).sendKeys("From data in expected date format");
  ```
- Enter `To` date :-

  ```
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[data-bind*='To'] > input.datetime-picker-date"))).sendKeys("To date in expected date format");
  ```